# Google Sheets IMPORTXML Resource at URL not found ( Is this possible at all? )

Tags: google-sheets-formula

=IMPORTXML("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/rafael-toloi/marktwertverlauf/spieler/72441","//*[@id='main']/main/div[3]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWMtL.png)/section/a[2]/div/div/div[2]/span[2]")

results in: Resource at url not found error

- I copied the website address
- I copied the Xpath from the site's inspect part
- I changed the "main" to 'main' to get the line accepted

Inspect part (I try to import the number 112):

```
                <h3 class="quick-fact__headline">Serie A</h3>
                <div class="quick-fact__box">
                    <div class="quick-fact__circle">
                    <div class="quick-fact__icon quick-fact__icon--0">
                    <div class="quick-fact__icon-wrapper">
                    <img 
 src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/logo/mediumquad/it1.pnglm=1632134907" title="Serie A" alt="Serie A" class="logo" />                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                <div class="quick-fact__content">
                            <span class="quick-fact__content--small">Rank</span>
                            <span class="quick-fact__content--large">112</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <p class="quick-fact__footnote">Ranked number 112 among all players of the Serie A</p>
                </div>
            </a>
```

[The image is a copy of the actual website's code, highlighted the line in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWMtL.png)

Your input is appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, the site refuses to fetch data by importxml.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data by script

```
function rank() {
  var url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/rafael-toloi/marktwertverlauf/spieler/72441'
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { followRedirects: true, muteHttpExceptions: true })
    .getContentText()
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm, "")
  var regExp = new RegExp(/Ranked number \d+ among all players of the Serie A/);
  Logger.log(regExp.exec(html)[0])
}
```

[image]

### edit

if you want to put the rank into a specific cell, try

```
function rank() {
  var url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/rafael-toloi/marktwertverlauf/spieler/72441'
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { followRedirects: true, muteHttpExceptions: true })
    .getContentText()
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm, "")
  var regExp = new RegExp(/Ranked number \d+ among all players of the Serie A/);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1').setValue(regExp.exec(html)[0].match(/\d+/)[0])
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. This is very helpful and very encouraging. Now I just need to figure out how to put the number 112 into a specified cell in the specified sheet. I will do this for all the players in the team and also bring in just one more attribute. I am so happy to see your reply.

Answer (score 0):

use script from previous question and then:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(rank(), "\d+")*1
```